# GET https://127.0.0.1:9000/peerjs/peerjs/id?ts=14993271469660.591159722513086 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, peerjs

I have created a simple video chat app using javascript's webRTC library peerjs.
And now I am trying to deploy the site on **zeit.co**. But I get the error when a peerjs instance gets created
Below is the code where I have mentioned ports and host to run the server

**Server side code**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

const srv = server.listen(3000)

app.use('/peerjs', require('peer').ExpressPeerServer(srv, {
    debug: true
}))

const users = []
const connections = []

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server running')
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

})
```

**Client side code**

```
const peerObj = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  path: '/peerjs',
  debug: 3,
  config: {icerServers: [
    { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
      credential: 'muazkh',
      username: 'webrtc@live.com' }
  ]}
}

peer = new Peer(peerObj)
```

- List item

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a solution for my question. Actually peer server runs on http, and for making it run on https, we have to generate a ssl key and certificate. Even after generating the keys and certificates it will only run on local host and the systems connected to that network.

There is a peer server hosted on heroku, so it is running on https, rather than running your own peer server, we can mention the path of the heroku peer server and then host the app on some hosting website, The app will run properly. Below is my new client side code

```
peer = new Peer({host:'peerjs-server.herokuapp.com', secure:true, port:443})
```

and this will run the app properly.

Comment: my app still works on local. It shows the connection has been established but couldn't see their stream.

Answer (score 0):

PeerJS's default port is 9000, which is also what the error suggests: it's trying to connect to port 9000 of `127.0.0.1`, but your server is running on port 3000.

Try adding the port number explicitly:

```
const peerObj = {
  host : '127.0.0.1',
  port : 3000,
  ...
}
```

You may also need to set `secure : false`, because your server doesn't support TLS.

Comment: previously I have explicitly mentioned the port at that time it was giving me an error below
**GET https://127.0.0.1:3000/peerjs/peerjs/id?ts=14993271469660.591159722513086 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Comment: I have hosted the site on zeit.co a free website hosting site for providing secure connections(https). I think the peerjs server is not working on zeit. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Try replacing `'127.0.0.1'` for the `host` option to the external IP-address of your Zeit server.

Comment: this did not help

Comment: yeah its the same

Comment: That's strange, because `127.0.0.1` is not hardcoded in PeerJS so it _has_ to be provided as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you dont want to depend herokuapp as Aish said

you can run on the terminal:

```
npm install peer
```

Then your server.js you add: `

```
 //Peer server
    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

  const { PeerServer } = require('peer');
  const peerServer = PeerServer({ port: 443, 
                                path: '/' ,
                                ssl: {
                                    key: privateKey,
                                    cert: certificate
                                  }
                            
                            });
```

`
The privatekey and certificates are needed for HTTPS. Make sure to have them on the paths where they are fetched.
Make sure that on client side (script run on index.html) you have:

```
myPeer = new Peer({host:'/', 
                  secure:true,
                   port:443,
                path: '/'})
```

Comment: Do you use apache reverse proxy for this setup?

Comment: Sorry, Zahra, I don't know what is this but it was not needed for my setup